# What is the purpose of bitwise_or in Python PEG?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9, peg, python-3.10

What does `bitwise_or` mean in PEG grammar? More accurately, there are lots of `bitwise_or` in contexts where it's not even parsing for | yet there are occurrences. Does `bitwise_or` serve any other purpose in PEG other than being the | in Python?

Example extracted from Python PEG:-

```
comparison[expr_ty]:
    | a=bitwise_or b=compare_op_bitwise_or_pair+ {
        _PyAST_Compare(
            a,
            CHECK(asdl_int_seq*, _PyPegen_get_cmpops(p, b)),
            CHECK(asdl_expr_seq*, _PyPegen_get_exprs(p, b)),
            EXTRA) }
    | bitwise_or
```

**Note the word `bitwise_or` here. The question is about that not the vertical bar in PEG.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "bitwise or operator" aka `|` has the [lowest precedence of regular binary operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). The only binary operators with lower precedence are [comparison operators, which are subject to chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) – for example, `a < b < c` is roughly equivalent to `a < b and b < c` – and thus behave specially.

For a PEG parser, precedence is usually encoded using [precedence climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser#Precedence_climbing_method). That means a *lower* precedence clause matches either itself or the *next* precedence clause. As such, the operator precedence "`|` < `^` < `&` < ..." is encoded in a ladder of bitwise or, bitwise xor, bitwise and, and so on:

```
bitwise_or:
    | bitwise_or '|' bitwise_xor 
    | bitwise_xor
bitwise_xor:
    | bitwise_xor '^' bitwise_and 
    | bitwise_and
bitwise_and:
    | bitwise_and '&' shift_expr 
    | shift_expr
```

This makes `bitwise_or` the "entry point" that matches all binary operators: it may defer to `bitwise_xor`, which may defer to `bitwise_and`, and so on to the highest-precedence operator. Notably, it means the *grammar rule* `bitwise_or` can match input that does not contain *the operation* "bitwise or" – for example, `bitwise_or` matches `a ^ b`.

Thus, `bitwise_or` is used in any position a binary operator may occur.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.